# Value of sum and uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-\log x)\log^{n}x$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Can you prove that this series converges uniformly with $x>0$? And can you calculate the sum?

I found that the derivative is $0$ when $x \ge e^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$. So i think that $\forall n \ge e^{\frac{\delta}{\delta+1}}$, with $\delta > 0$, we have $\sup_{x\ge\delta} f_n (x) = f_n (\delta)$, but i can't prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-\log\delta)\log^{n}\delta$ converges (it must).

Comment: Hint: $\sum = (1-\log x) \sum \log^nx$, the sum is similar to that of $\sum x^n$

Comment: Well for $x=e^2$, the sum becomes $-\sum_n 2^n$ which doesn't converge. Note that for $0 < x < e$, the sum converges since $(1-\log(x))$ is a finite constant that can be put out of the sum and $\log(x) < 1$, hence it is bounded by the classical geometric series. And for the case $x=e$, the sum become $\sum_n 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum converges uniformly when
$|\log x|<1$
or
$1/e<x<e$.

If this holds, the sum is a ordinary geometric series with sum, ignoring the
$1-\log x$, of
$\frac1{1-\log x}$
so the whole expression is just 1.

Comment: but it converges also if $x = e$, in fact the sum becomes 0

Comment: But not uniformly since the expression is not continuous there.

Comment: The sum converges uniformly on *compact* subsets of $(1/e,e)$, but not in a neighborhood of $1/e$ or of $e$.